# Assume $T$ is a complex operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $T$ is a complex operator such that $T^{2}=T$. Prove that $Tr(T)$ is a non-negative integer.

There is a remark in my book, Suppose the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{T}(x)$ factors intro linear factores:

$\chi_{T}(x)=(x-\lambda_{1})(x-\lambda_{2})...(x-\lambda_{n})$ where $\lambda_{i}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ repeated with their algebraic multiplicity. The the trace of $T$ is the of the eigenvalues of $T$ (taken with their algebraic multiplicity(:

$Tr(T)=\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}+...+\lambda_{n}$

I beilve I have to use this remark but I did not get how would I write $T^{2}=T$

Comment: If $T^2 = T$, what eigenvalues can $T$ have?

Comment: When in it self-adjoint it would have a real eigenvalue

Comment: A common version of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem states that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has the same roots as the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T^2=T$, $T^2-T = 0$. Therefore $T$ satifies the polynomial $p(x) = x^2-x = x(x-1)$. The minimal polynomial of $T$ must divide $p(x)$. Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial. Then $m(x) = x$ or $m(x) = x-1$ or $m(x) = p(x)$. In any of these cases, the eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of $m(x)$ are among $0$ and $1$. So taking the sum of the eigenvalues just amounts to adding $0$'s and $1$'s. Thus the trace is non-negative.

Notice that each of these cases can possibly occur.

If $T = 0$, then $m(x)=x$ and $T^2 = T$.

If $T = I$, then $m(x)=x-1$ and $T^2 = T$.

For the last case let $T$ be the linear transformation whose matrix with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $m(x) = x(x-1)$ and $T^2 = T$.

Comment: I think all you need is thevery first line: if we already know the eigenvalues of $\;T\;$ are only $\;0,1\;$ , the sum of these is a real non-negative number.

Comment: Knowing that the minimal polynomial divides $x(x-1)$ is certainly good enough (I suppose you also need the fact that all of the eigenvalues show up as roots of the minimal polynomial). I was just adding more detail for the sake of understanding.